# Autohotkey, Change Hotstring on Shortcut

Tags: autohotkey

is it possible (how?) to change the Hotstring and the Endchars with another Hotkey?

A:

```
#Hotstring EndChars `n `t
#Hotstring o
;#Hotstring *
```

B

```
;#Hotstring EndChars `n `t
;#Hotstring o
#Hotstring *
```

I want to switch between direct input (B) and input after an Endchar (A).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directives cannot be executed conditionally. The only solution I can see is to use an included script that you can change the content this way:

```
F1::
FileAppend,
(
#Hotstring EndChars ``n ``t
#Hotstring o
), %A_ScriptDir%\Hotstring_Directives_tmp.ahk
Sleep, 300
FileMove, %A_ScriptDir%\Hotstring_Directives_tmp.ahk, %A_ScriptDir%\Hotstring_Directives.ahk, 1 ; overwrite
Sleep, 300 
Reload
return


F2::
FileAppend,
(
#Hotstring *
), %A_ScriptDir%\Hotstring_Directives_tmp.ahk
Sleep, 300
FileMove, %A_ScriptDir%\Hotstring_Directives_tmp.ahk, %A_ScriptDir%\Hotstring_Directives.ahk, 1 ; overwrite
Sleep, 300 
Reload
return

; ...

#Include %A_ScriptDir%\Hotstring_Directives.ahk

; your Hotstrings here
```

Note that you have to create the script Hotstring_Directives.ahk manually if it doesn't already exist.